# После перезагрузки страницы не сохраняется выбор switcher (checkbox)

Tags: jquery

Использую в работе кастомный checkbox [jquery.switcher](https://github.com/djanix/jquery.switcher), но при выборе checkbox и дальнейшем сохранении выбранных данных, перезагрузке страницы выбранные значения switcher-а не сохраняется на странице. В админку на сервер значение передается и сохраняется.
Пытался это решить так:

```
$(function() {
    var switcherEl = $('#id_order_status_reminder, #id_launch_status, #id_help_and_tips').switcher();

    switcherEl.switcher('setValue', true);

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {

            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                switcherEl.switcher('setValue', true);

            } else {
                switcherEl.switcher('setValue', false);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Но это не работает.
Прошу помощи в решении данной проблемы. 
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вам состояние свитчера хранить или на сервере и выставлять при каждой загрузке или надо хранить его на клиенте в куке или local storage

Comment: это вопрос или совет?

Comment: на чистых checkbox-ах все работает отлично, и сохраняется, и передается на сервер, а вот на кастомном только значения передаются на сервер, а сам визуальный выбор на странице не сохраняется.

Comment: Можно использовать localStorage

Comment: localStorage не совсем хотелось бы, ведь данные передаются на сервер и записываются, идея у меня была такова что бы получать данные уже с сервера, проверять на :checked и в зависимости от этого инициализировать switcher, но что-то я не могу понять почему не получается